# Building a dropdown menu with additional row of button options in Flutter?

Tags: android, user-interface, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm hoping to replicate this UI for the dropdown menu in Flutter. I've attempted to do it with a dropdown menu where the selected options light up in the same way as the screens below.

[image] [image]

Building the initial dropdown menu with options seems simple enough, but I'm having trouble understanding how to build a final row into the dropdown menu with the two buttons ("Create a Circle" and "Join a Circle" here). Has anyone tried something similar to build a more customized dropdown menu with additional functionality beyond just the options?